# How does an Objective-C method have access to the callee's ivars?

Tags: objective-c, oop, instance-variables, self

I was reading Apple's documentation, [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://andrewd.ces.clemson.edu/courses/cpsc102/notes/ObjC.pdf) (PDF link). On pg. 18, under *The Receiver’s Instance Variables*, I saw this.

> A method has automatic access to the receiving object’s instance
>   variables. You don’t need to pass them to the method as parameters.
>   For example, the `primaryColor` method illustrated above takes no
>   parameters, yet it can find the primary color for `otherRect` and return
>   it. Every method assumes the receiver and its instance variables,
>   without having to declare them as parameters.
>
> This convention simplifies Objective-C source code. It also supports
>   the way object-oriented programmers think about objects and messages.
>   Messages are sent to receivers much as letters are delivered to your
>   home. Message parameters bring information from the outside to the
>   receiver; they don’t need to bring the receiver to itself.

I am trying to better understand what they are describing; is this like Python's `self` parameter, or style?

Comment: Don't compare Objective-C to Python...

Comment: I am looking for additional ways to improve this.

Comment: By the way, this question seems perfectly OK to me. The guy is just asking for some clarifications about the documentation, coming from a python background. No reason to close IMHO...

Comment: And, in reality, Python was very much inspired by Objective-C.   Python's Benevolent Dictator For Life, Guido van Rossum, was an avid NeXT user and wrote quite a bit of code on the platform.   The explicit `self` parameter in Python is very much like the implicit `self` in Objective-C, but much like the rest of Python's philosophy, avoids magic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

So Objective-C methods are "just" function pointers, and instances are "just" C structs.

A method has two hidden parameters. The first one is `self`(the current instance), the second `_cmd` (the method's selector).

But what the documentation is describing in page 18 is the access to the class instance variables from a method.

It just says a method of a class can access the instance variables of that class.
It's pretty basic from an object-oriented perspective, but not from a C perspective.

It also say that you can't access instance variables from another class instance, unless they are public.

Comment: And the _reason_ that instance variable access is possible is the hidden `self` parameter. The compiler knows that, inside an instance method, an access to an ivar should really be `self->ivar`

Answer (score 1):

While I would not say that it is a "slam" against Python, it is most certainly referring to the Python style of Object Orientation (which, in honesty, is derived from the "pseudo-object orientation" available in C (whether it is truly OO or not is a debate for another forum)).

It is good to remember that Python has a very different concept of scope from the rest of the world — each method more or less exists in its own little reality. This is contrasted with more "self-aware" languages which either have a "this" variable or an implicit instance construct of some form.